# Masstransit published messages disappear from queue

Tags: masstransit

In process A, I'm using 
`Bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>`
to create client then using 
`client.GetResponse<TResponse1, TResponse12>(request)`
to get response from process B.

In process B I respond to the request using `consumeContext.RespondAsync(@event)` as well as publishing the event with `consumeContext.Publish(@event)`

I have a process C subscribe to the published event.

So I have process A, B and C up and running, then I stop process C.
I send the request in process A and the queue for process C receives a message, but after a few seconds, the message disappear from the queue.

I've check the config the queue is configured with durable=true and autodelete=false.

If I use fire and forget (send the message to end point) instead of request/response in A, and only publish the event in B. then the message stays on the queue for C.

Is this by design?
Also I noticed that if I get a message on the queue by using fire and forget, the all the messages come after stays on the queue regardless if it was created using request/response or not.

See below screenshot, during highlighted period, the messages are taken off the queue without consumer ack.
[image: Messages taken off queue without consumer ack]

Comment: Messages don#t just disappear from queues, they only get consumed. If you have your original setup, try going to RMQ management UI and check consumers for the queue for that process C, there should be something there.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I have checked the consumers for that queue after I stopped process C. There is no consumer. Messages don't disappear if I don't respond and only publish the event in B.

Comment: Maybe you can post the code where you set up the bus for B and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it turns out, this is a bug. The request `TimeToLive` is being applied to every message produced by the request consumer, which is why it eventually disappears from the queue.

[Fixed](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1871)

Will be released as 6.3.1 probably tonight.